# Adding Dynamic Fields in Bucket Search Results

Tags: content-search, buckets

We are trying to add dynamic fields in a bucket search results view. We want to display custom fields. In the previous versions of sitecore there use to be a DynamicFields pipeline. As stated in the [sitecore 9 release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes), the pipeline has been removed.

How can we achieve this using sitecore 9?

Comment: This should be a comment but the button is disabled due to too low reputation (seriously who thought that was a good idea?). I want to point out that Soren Kruse's answer doesn't seem to work anymore in sitecore 9.2. You will get the following error:
```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not find method: Process. Pipeline: /sitecore[database="SqlServer" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"]/pipelines/buckets.dynamicFields[patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config"]/processor[type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.DynamicFields.FetchDynamicFieldValues, Sitecore.Buckets"]'
```
So it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same issue, luckily it isn't too hard to re-implement. I believe this should work exactly like before, but we might have skipped something we didn't need so just be aware of that.

#### AddDynamicFields.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.FillItem;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using YourSolution.DynamicFields

namespace YourSolution
{
    public class AddDynamicFields : FillItemProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(FillItemArgs args)
        {
            foreach (var searchResultItem in args.ResultItems.OfType<SitecoreUISearchResultItem>())
            {
                Language itemLanguage;
                Language.TryParse(searchResultItem.Language, out itemLanguage);

                var version = Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(searchResultItem.Version);

                var item =
                    Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(searchResultItem.ItemId, itemLanguage, version) ??
                    Context.Database.GetItem(searchResultItem.ItemId, itemLanguage, version);

                if (item == null)
                    return;

                LoadDynamicFields(item, searchResultItem);
            }
        }

        private static void LoadDynamicFields(Item innerItem, SitecoreUISearchResultItem sitecoreItem)
        {
            if (sitecoreItem.DynamicFields == null)
                sitecoreItem.DynamicFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            var dynamicFieldsArgs = new DynamicFieldsArgs { InnerItem = innerItem};
            var corePipelineManager = ContentSearchManager.Locator.GetInstance<BaseCorePipelineManager>();
            corePipelineManager.Run("buckets.dynamicFields", dynamicFieldsArgs);

            sitecoreItem.DynamicFields = dynamicFieldsArgs.DynamicFields.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

#### DynamicFieldsArgs.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace YourSolution.DynamicFields
{
    public class DynamicFieldsArgs : BucketsPipelineArgs
    {
        public Item InnerItem { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, string> DynamicFields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

#### DynamicFieldsProcessor.cs

```
using Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines;

namespace YourSolution.DynamicFields
{
    public abstract class DynamicFieldsProcessor : BucketsPipelineProcessor<DynamicFieldsArgs>
    {
    }
}
```

#### Config patch

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <buckets.fillItem>
        <processor type="YourSolution.AddDynamicFields, YourSolution" />
      </buckets.fillItem>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in Soren Kruse's answer is that he is defining a custom DynamicFieldsArgs class. The processor that sitecore uses uses a different class (but with the same name) so this will break. The fix is to just use the class that sitecore gives you.

I modified Soren Kruse's answer for my own needs where I just wanted to show values from the index itself (currently its loading all fields which might be a bit much though):

```
    public class AddDynamicFields : FillItemProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(FillItemArgs args)
        {
            foreach (var searchResultItem in args.ResultItems.OfType<SitecoreUISearchResultItem>())
            {
                var dynamicFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                foreach (var field in searchResultItem.Fields)
                {
                    dynamicFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(field.Key, field.Value?.ToString()));
                }

                searchResultItem.DynamicFields = dynamicFields;
            }
        }
    }
```